# npm: Use explicit package.json from subdirectory

Tags: node.js, npm, bamboo

I want to run

```
npm install
```

from `/earth/sea/fish/`.

In above directory there is a `package.json` which should be used by the command. AFAIK I am *not* able to `cd` into that directory, because I am using Bamboo to do this.

Comment: Did you try that? It should work.

Comment: You mean like this? http://i.imgur.com/lnbnA43.png

Comment: Could you clarify your exact directory structure, what the current directory is, and where you want to install the package.json from?

Comment: `$ cd node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/` and 
`$ npm install` needs to be done in order to deal with https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2285. We need to do this in Bamboo, since mongoose's maintainer did unfortunately not yet fix this dependency. I am doing this fix on every operating system where we use mongoose.